# Why does my device show different auto layout from the simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, stackview

I have a stack view which is anchored to a scrollview.  I'm getting it to display exactly how I want it to look on my iPhone 6s Plus device, as show below:

[image]

However, using the exact same version, when I run it on the iPhone 6s Plus simulator, my layout extends beyond the edges of the view on the right, and is similarly thrown off on other devices that I select.  Any suggestions as to why the device is working, the simulator is not working?

See below, Simulator:

[image]

I've tried using a number of different ways to solve it, including using the new "safe area layout guides," but I can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: show all the constraints given to view.

Comment: seem like the screen size of your simulator and you device is difference

Comment: Can you show what the current constrains are?

Comment: You probably have some ambiguity constraints, which you should fix them. For more help give more information about your constraints

Answer (score 1):

Check your constrains of View. Start to give constrains to SE Device then run on other device.

apply constrains as below you will get output.

**Here is a constrains of views**

**How Sour? View**

[image]

**Very Sour View**

[image]

**Mildly Sour View**

[image]

**Mild View**

[image]

**Sweet View**

[image]